Why do I have several files with uncovered lines from 1 to N after upgrading our Vitest coverage provider from C8 to V8?
We recently upgraded our Vue app from Vitest 0.31.4 to 2.1.2, and part of that upgrade involved switching coverage providers from C8 to V8. We're having an issue where multiple files now have missing coverage starting at line 1, and going to some (seemingly) arbitrary point in the .vue file we're testing. I understand that V8 handles source maps differently than C8 did, but I'm having trouble understanding why some files now have practically no coverage, whereas when using C8, they were well over 90% for statement/branch/function/line. For example:
---------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                                   | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
  ContractCard.vue                     |   41.31 |    72.22 |   33.33 |   41.31 | 1-95,98-121       
  PropertyCard.vue                     |    8.41 |    73.17 |   22.22 |    8.41 | 1-239,244         
  VendorCard.vue                       |   33.82 |    69.69 |      50 |   33.82 | 1-227             
---------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

I've added console log statements to parts of the code from 1 to N that are supposedly uncovered, and can confirm they're being reached when I run the tests for these files. I've had some success importing every component used in the .vue file into the spec.ts file and including them in mountWithVuetify.
I've been trying to figure this out for a few days and I'm basically stuck. There are about 20 files in my app where this is happening, out of roughly 300 test files. Any ideas?

Try to maybe not do both a big migration and a coverage provider change at the same time, might be tricky to troubleshoot, go incremental.
